# autodesk forge java exception

Tags: java, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk

downloading (https://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/environment/setup/java?id=files-and-folders)  and Main class Running - > console is complete but open viewer.html error

use localserver tomcat8.5

```
google console log
1.Logger.js:175 No access token is provided, but authorization requested. This is a problem.
2.Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized)
3.viewer.html:83 onDocumentLoadFailure() - errorCode:4



Main.java console
***** Sending createBucket request
***** Sending uploadFile request
Error creating bucket : {"reason":"Bucket already exists"}
***** Response for uploadFile: 
Uploaded object Details - Location: https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets/forge-java-sample-app-tud2dd7bnd8ltbaegqee5ua175mdulau/objects/my-elephant.obj, Size:12501
***** Sending Derivative API translate request
***** Response for Translating File to SVF: class Job {
    result: success
    urn: dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6Zm9yZ2UtamF2YS1zYW1wbGUtYXBwLXR1ZDJkZDdibmQ4bHRiYWVncWVlNXVhMTc1bWR1bGF1L215LWVsZXBoYW50Lm9iag
    acceptedJobs: class JobAcceptedJobs {
        output: {formats=[{type=svf, views=[3d]}]}
    }
}
***** Sending getManifest request
***** Haven't finished translating your file to SVF - status: pending, progress:0% complete
***** Haven't finished translating your file to SVF - status: inprogress, progress:0% complete
***** Finished translating your file to SVF - status: success, progress:complete
***** Opening SVF file in viewer with urn:dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6Zm9yZ2UtamF2YS1zYW1wbGUtYXBwLXR1ZDJkZDdibmQ4bHRiYWVncWVlNXVhMTc1bWR1bGF1L215LWVsZXBoYW50Lm9iag
```

sorry I'm not good at english

I have verified that Main.class receives a token. However, no token is provided in viewer.html.

Answer (score 0):

Data/program states in back end is not automatically shared with the front end - be sure to use AJAX to call the backend and fetch the URN for Viewer.

You can refer to the code [here](https://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/viewer/2legged/ui?id=forgeviewerjs) to fetch and provide the URN to Viewer:

```
function getForgeToken(callback) {
  fetch('/api/forge/oauth/token').then(res => {
    res.json().then(data => {
      callback(data.access_token, data.expires_in);
    });
  });
}
```

Like we went through before you can clone the [full sample project](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/learn.forge.viewmodels/tree/java) and go from there.